# Problems with Trade payments and Braintree

Tags: magento2, error, payment, braintree

So we have a problem with our M2 site. We have a retail site and a trade site. We use Braintree. On the retail site customers are able to place an order fine using their debit/credit cards however on the trade site it is returning an error (attached) however it is taking payment. We are using two different Merchant ID's at first we had one and thought that was the problem however now we have two seperate ID's it still isn't working.

Any suggestions?[image]

We really need to get this up and running however Braintree have said it isn't a problem on their end so something is going wrong in Magento.

I have attached the console received: 
[image]

Comment: What do the log files say? any errors in var/log/system.log or exception.log any errors in the server access/error logs.

Comment: @DanCarlyon I have attached the console into the main text.

Comment: You've got a 400 Bad Request status code there. That would be my first investigation point, that should have triggered some sort of error/exception within magento in the system.log and/or exception.log in your `[Magento Root]/var/log/` directory